# How do I target my navbar in this code?

Tags: jquery, function

My code should make my header get thinner while I scroll. My navbar stays immobile, but I would like to add a padding to my navbar while it scrolls.

However, I can't seem to target my navbar, can you suggest ideas?

Here's the fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/MGc7y/

```
$(function(){
    $('#header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('#header');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 600);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'90px'
            }, 600);
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Its preatty simple, you never get into `if`

try this:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

not

```
$('body').scrollTop()
```

Get Firebug for Firefox and try to debug next time like this for example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   console.log($('body').scrollTop());
```

result: always `0`

---

I dont understand you question/problem, you should make a fiddle.net or at least some HTML markup. What do you mean by: **I can't seem to target my navbar in the code.** ?

Here some other suggestions that might help:

```
$(function(){
    //Here is better, otherwise you selecting it on scroll x times for no reason..
    var $nav = $('#header'); 

    //Also on DOMready
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
            //if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') { // if you dont have an other reason, you could let it away
            $nav.stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 600);
            //}
    } else {
        //if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
        $nav.stop().animate({
            height:'90px'
        }, 600);
        //}  
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a fiddle that you can check!